# Рефлексия в Kotlin. Как узнать, является ли поле Nullable?

Tags: java, рефлексия, kotlin

Каким образом можно динамично (то есть, во время рантайма) проверить, является ли поле Nullable?

Пытался нагуглить и поэкспериментировать с Kotlin и Java классами самостоятельноo, но ничего не вышло, может быть кто-то сталкивался?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ответили в итоге на английском StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277991/kotlin-how-to-check-if-the-field-is-nullable-via-reflection#40278279)

Перевод:

Вы можете проверить допустимость null, с помощью флага [`isMarkedNullable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/is-marked-nullable.html).

Следующий код

```
class MyClass(val nullable: Long?, val notNullable: MyClass)
MyClass::class.declaredMemberProperties.forEach {
    println("Property $it isMarkedNullable=${it.returnType.isMarkedNullable}")
}
```

Напечатает:

```
Property val MyClass.notNullable: stack.MyClass isMarkedNullable=false
Property val MyClass.nullable: kotlin.Long? isMarkedNullable=true
```

Выдержка из документации(выделения мои):

> Для типов Kotlin, это означает, что значение null допускается для представления типов. На практике это означает, что типы будут определены со знаком вопроса (`?`) в конце. Для не-Kotlin типов, это значит, что тип или symbol, который будет определен с этим типом помечается аннотацией типа *javax.annotation.Nullable*.
>
> **Важно, что даже если `isMarkedNullable` вернет *false*, значения типа все еще могут быть `null`**. Это может случиться если тип это тип параметра:
>
> ```
> fun <T> foo(t: T) {
>     // isMarkedNullable == false for t's type, but t can be null here 
> }
> ```

Также, нужно учитывать, что поле может быть отмечено как NotNull, но при этом всё равно может иметь нулевое значение (насколько я понял, происходит из-за проблем с совместимостью Kotlin и других JVM языков).

Comment: стоило все-таки перевести ответ, а не просто скопировать

Comment: @Grundy Вопрос не столько важный, но переведу, ок.

Comment: Дело не в важности вопроса, а в том, что это ruSO, и тут не только вопросы должны быть на русском, но и ответы.